# How do I access an Arabic letter least painfully in a mathematical text

Tags: symbols, letters

I write a mathematical text with the preamble

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter\let\TTTemp\cap\makeatother
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}




\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

I would like to access the Arabic letter Noon. How can I do it least painfully?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `fontspec` with option `nomath`, so that the usual packages take care of math typesetting,  and compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The  problem is to have a font that has arabic characters. All you have to know is the`U-code` of the character you want to use. Here is a example, in which I use `Arial`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\arabfont{Arial}
\newcommand\arabtext[1]{{\arabfont#1}}

\begin{document}
Here is the letter nun,  regular and boldface: \medskip

\arabtext{\LARGE\char"0646\quad\bfseries\char"0646}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I have the problem that the fontspec package requires Xetez or Luatex to function ....

Comment: Yes. Other solutions would require installing specific packages and fonts such as `arabtex`. It's only fontspec that gives you a simple access to any opentype or truetype font installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid working with Unicodes, I would recommend using the `arabtex` package ([lookup table here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX#Character_table)). Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\setarab

\begin{RLtext}
n
\end{RLtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If X is the Arabic letter Noon, I want to write X(A)=BCD.. where ABCD.. are latin letters or symbols. Could I do that with your approach?

Comment: No. If you want to mix Arabic and non-Arabic letters within one sentence/formula like your example, then `arabtex` is not the best option.